# Adding date and time to excel export in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I am new to Laravel and I am making a new project where I am exporting my schools data to a spreadsheet with maatwebsite, I have given it a title with the following code:

```
   public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            ['Staff Report'], [
                'staffid',
                'name',
                'emailaddress',
                'faculty',             
            ]
        ];
    }
```

What I want to accomplish is to have the date next to the title so it should be `Staff Report-04/05/21`

I tried to use date time but that relies on a created_at field in the db...Has anyone used this before?

Comment: You want to add a date to the title, which date you want to use ? Where does it comes from ?

Comment: I just want a real time date, like when its downloaded

Comment: `date("d/m/y")` should do the tricks then

Comment: @Maxime this works too!!1

Comment: @guycode12 All your descriptions that were posted as comments should be embedded into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow and Laravel.

So if you want to display the correct format then you have to map the data before export and specify columnFormats function.

For this you also have to use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat and use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date.

In my case, I am going to export the user's company's clients. Change the code according to your use case.

Ref. link - https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/format.html

Under the columnFormats function, you have to specify column title like (K) in my case and the "NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY" for the date format.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;

class ClientsExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithMapping, WithColumnFormatting
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return $user->company->clients;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Name',
            'Email',
            'Address',
            'Country',
            'Department',
            'Zip',
            'Fax',
            'Phone',
            'Mobile',
            'Date'
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'G' => 0,
            'H' => 0,
            'I' => '@',
            'J' => '@',
            'K' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY,
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @var Client $client
    */
    public function map($client): array
    {
        return [
            $client->name,
            $client->tax_id,
            $client->email,
            // other data
            $client->fax,
            $client->phone,
            $client->mobile,
            Date::dateTimeToExcel($client->created_at)
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: this works!! but its converting my commas to decimals and rounding it off... also the alignment of the values are left and right

Comment: are you talking about date format or number format of another field.

Comment: another field, I added a field for database version, for example one record would be in v18.5 and another would be v17

Comment: Try FORMAT_NUMBER_00 instead of 0 and check.

Comment: Read from this link. https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html